# Execute jar file from a deployed Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, jar, executable-jar

I have a Qt application which execute a jar file in command line:

```
cmd = new QProcess(this);
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-jar" << "desktop-1.0.jar";
cmd->start("java",  arguments);
```

It works because I putted desktop-1.0.jar at root of the project. But when I deploy, it doesn't works: `"Error: Unable to access jarfile desktop-1.0.jar"`

I tried to add desktop-1.0.jar to resources in myApp.pro: `RESOURCES += desktop-1.0.jar` but it doesn't change anything.

What I have to do to make it works now?

Comment: Where do you put `desktop-1.0.jar` file on deployment?

Comment: Nowhere, I thought the build take the resources too.
Where should I put it??

For information, I am on MacOS

Comment: do not place it in a resource, instead use the fullpath.

Comment: if you want to add it as a resource, you should add it in the qrc, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html for more info

Comment: @eyllanesc How can I use fullpath? When I will deploy, path will change. And I don't even find `desktop-1.0.jar` in the myApp.app folder, so which path should I use?